# JSF/PrimeFaces ajax updates breaks jQuery event listener function bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I am registering a `change` event listener for every `input` in the HTML using jQuery as below:

```
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(':input').each(function() {
                $(this).change(function() {
                    console.log('From docReady: ' + this.id);
                });
            });
        });

        function changeHandler() {
            console.log("from changeHandler");
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="topForm">
        <p:commandButton id="myButton" value="update"
                         action="#{testBean.submit}"
                         partialSubmit="true" process=":myForm:panel"
                         update=":myForm:panel" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <p:panel id="panel">
            <p:inputTextarea id="myTextarea"
                             value="#{testBean.val}"
                             onchange="changeHandler();"/>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Both `change` events are being triggered if the user changes the content of `myTextarea`. However after pressing the update button, which partially updates the `myTextarea`, only the changeHandler is triggering afterwards. The event bound in `$(document).ready()` is not triggering anymore.

Is this PrimeFaces related and/or an expected behavior? If yes then how can I ensure to trigger the second event without rerunning document ready script again.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As to the cause of your problem, the ajax request will update the HTML DOM tree with new HTML elements from the ajax response. Those new HTML elements do —obviously— not have the jQuery event handler function attached. However, the `$(document).ready()` isn't re-executed on ajax requests. You need to manually re-execute it.

This can be achieved in various ways. The simplest way is to use `$(document).on(event, selector, function)` instead of `$(selector).on(event, function)`. This is tied to the document and the given `functionRef` is always invoked when the given `eventName` is triggered on an element matching the given `selector`. So you never need to explicitly re-execute the function by JSF means.

```
$(document).on("change", ":input", function() {
    console.log("From change event on any input: " + this.id);
});
```

---

The alternative way is to explicitly re-execute the function yourself on complete of ajax request. This would be the only way when you're actually interested in immediately execute the function during the `ready`/`load` event (e.g. to directly apply some plugin specific behavior/look'n'feel, such as date pickers). First, you need to refactor the `$(document).ready()` job into a reusable function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    applyChangeHandler();
});

function applyChangeHandler() {
    $(":input").on("change", function() {
        console.log("From applyChangeHandler: " + this.id);
    });
}
```

*(note that I removed and simplified your completely unnecessary `$.each()` approach)*

Then, choose one of the following ways to re-execute it on complete of ajax request:

1. Use the `oncomplete` attribute of the PrimeFaces command button:

   ```
   oncomplete="applyChangeHandler()"
   ```
2. Use `<h:outputScript target="body">` instead of `$(document).ready()`,

   ```
   <h:outputScript id="applyChangeHandler" target="body">
       applyChangeHandler();
   </h:outputScript>
   ```

   and reference it in `update` attribute:

   ```
   update=":applyChangeHandler"
   ```
3. Use `<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">` to auto update it on every ajax request:

   ```
   <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
       <h:outputScript id="applyChangeHandler">
           applyChangeHandler();
       </h:outputScript>
   </p:outputPanel>
   ```
4. Use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:onloadScript>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/onloadScript) instead of `$(document).ready()`, `<h:outputScript>` and all on em.

   ```
   <o:onloadScript>applyChangeHandler();</o:onloadScript>
   ```

Comment: Or you could use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), which is the technique designed specifically to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: @Anthony: That works only on ajax requests which are executed via "plain jQuery" and on HTML DOM elements which are attached via "plain jQuery" because it has its own internal event listeners therefor.

Comment: All of my experience tells me neither of those statements is correct.

Comment: @BalusC. Thanks for posting. It seems the 3rd choice is suitable for my use case. I am planning to put that code block in the facelet template. And for this 3rd way, I removed $(document).ready(function(){} otherwise the handler is registered twice on initial page load, then put the autoUpdatable p:outputPanel to the end of the body manually. If I eventually find myself implementing the functionalities that Omnifaces already offers, definitely will give it a try. :)

Comment: @BalusC. Is there any way to just execute the script on newly added elements only after ajax response? Otherwise the handler is bound to the element again and again.

Comment: You could use a more specific selector or use `$.off()` first and then `$.on()`.

Comment: Note that I improved the answer as per new jQuery's `$(document).on()`.

Comment: @BalusC I bet my upvote brought you here to update it. I liked 3rd way described before, you shouldnt have deleted it :P

Comment: @smitalm: fair point, I undeleted it and instead put it as "update".

Comment: @BalusC it's the best answer I've seen in that topic, Actually one upvote is not enough for you :)