# Jquery event not called after update

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a pretty simple JSF form on my hand like so:

```
<h:inputText id="number" value="#{bean.value}"
styleClass="integer" onkeyup="update()" />
```

I have a jQuery selector as well like this:

```
jQuery(document)
        .ready(
                    jQuery(".integer")
                            .keydown(
                                    function(event) {
                                        //do your stuf


        });
```

Now, this function is getting triggered pretty well, until I update the container around this input. It is a ui:repeat by the way. The update() method only refreshes a label. After the update the function is never triggered until I reload the page. This jquery included from a file in the head part, but is is still there after the update, function is not triggered however? How can I make it work again after update?

Comment: may i suggest you yo add your function as a callback inside your update function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite slow tonight have been working all day, what do you mean?

Comment: the update() method refreshing the label should have a callback inside it in a way to initialize your other method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces's partial update breaks JQuery event binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400624/primefacess-partial-update-breaks-jquery-event-binding)

Answer (score 1):

As others have already answered: When you update the container the event handler is not attached anymore and your need to reattach it.

However, another option to this is using jquery`s [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

So use something like this (untested though):

```
jQuery(document)
    .ready(
        $(document).on("keydown", '.integer', function (event) {
            //do your stuf
    }));
```

Comment: @BalusC How am I going to test OPs code (that I don't have)? I am using the `on()` function in my application and it works very well. I am just trying to give an idea of the code and writing "untested" should imply that it might not work to just copy and paste it. Are you saying I should leave the code out? Or the answer altogether and just write a comment that jquerys `on()` mechanism would be an alternative?

Comment: Sorry, I was apparently having a bad morning and mixing posts. Yours looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't work after you update because the element isn't bound event anymore, so you should create a Javascript's function to solve this issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
jQuery(".integer")
                            .keydown(
                                    function(event) {
                                        //do your stuf


        });
};
jQuery(document)
        .ready(test();
              );      
</script>
```

Component update your target component should call this `test()` function, like:

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="test();" update=":COMPONENT_ID_HERE" ..../>
```