# Execute a JavaScript method, when a p:outputLabel is rendered

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am rendering a `<p:outputLabel>`, when validation failed like this.

```
<p:outputLabel value="Validation Failed"
               styleClass="validation-error"
               rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}" 
               onfocus="myMethod();"/>
```

I want to execute a JavaScript function namely `myMethod()`, when this label is rendered. I also used `onfocus` attribute but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring potential design problems (perhaps you *actually* need a [document event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14400791)?), you can achieve this by simply nesting a `<script>` (or `<h:outputScript>`) in the component.

```
<p:outputLabel ...><script>myFunction()</script></p:outputLabel>
```

I only renamed "myMethod" to "myFunction" conform JavaScript terminology.

Comment: Thanks @BlausC this has solved my problem. Can you explain why onfocus attribute is not working?

Comment: You're welcome. It works only when the element gets focus. The element doesn't automagically get focus when it's simply being added to DOM. The enduser has to focus it manually (or you have to run some JavaScript to trigger focus event on that, but that's nonsense as you could as good immediately invoke that function instead).

Comment: It's great, but can I refer to the component with a variable? Thanks.

Comment: @László: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6045307