# How to open primefaces selectOneMenu on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have implemented a selectOneMenu from primefaces and all works as it should when I click it to open.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="dropdownMenu" value="#{viewBean.selectedItem}" styleClass="dropdown">
    <p:ajax listener="#{controllerBean.onSelectedItemChanged}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item A" itemValue="A" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item B" itemValue="B" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item C" itemValue="C" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

But what I want is to open it when the mouse cursor is over it and close when it leaves.

I tried implementing the mouseenter and mouseleave functions and use them to click the dropdown but without success.

```
$('.dropdown').mouseenter(function(event) {
    console.log("IN dropdown");
    $(this).click();
});
$('.dropdown').mouseleave(function(event) {
    console.log("OUT dropdown");
    $(this).click();
});
```

The message is printed in the console, so the event is detected, and the click is also detected since I have also tried printing something when that happens, but the dropdown won't open programmatically.

**UPDATE**

Changing the click event for the trigger inside the dropdown makes this open and close correctly.

```
$('.dropdown').mouseenter(function(event) {
    console.log("IN dropdown");
    $('.ui-selectonemenu-trigger',this).click();
});
$('.dropdown').mouseleave(function(event) {
    console.log("OUT dropdown");
    $('.ui-selectonemenu-trigger',this).click();
});
```

The problem now is that when I move the mouse to select an option, the menu is closed because the mouse left the dropdown area.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try .trigger('click') instead of click();

Comment: Doesn't work, `.trigger('click')` has the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your select menu as

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="dropdownMenu" value="#{viewBean.selectedItem}" styleClass="dropdown" widgetvar="selectTest">
```

and use the following javascript

```
$('.dropdown').mouseenter(function(event) {
    PF('selectTest').show();
});


$('.dropdown').mouseleave(function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.toElement || event.relatedTarget);
    if(!($target.hasClass("ui-selectonemenu-items") || $target.hasClass("ui-selectonemenu-panel"))){
        PF('selectTest').hide();
    }

});

$('.ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper').mouseleave(function(event) {
    PF('selectTest').hide();
});
```

Comment: It's better to use `$(document).on("mouseenter", ".dropdown", callback)`, so it keeps working after the component gets ajax-updated. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/14400624